# JavaScript Disabling the effect of external CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a simple enough situation where i have three readonly input texts, on hover i change their backgrounds through CSS, and on click i want to change the clicked box's background permanently (till the next one is clicked) but as soon i click on one, the hover effect of CSS gets disabled and the color no longer changes on hover.. Code and output is below:

```js
function Calculate(id)
{
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("options");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i].style.background = 'none';
    }
    document.getElementById(id).style.background = '#d1d1d1';
}
```

```css
.options:hover {
 background:#d1d1d1;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="options" id="3" value="3" style="width: 30px;text-align:center" onclick="Calculate(this.id)" readonly> 
    
<input type="text" class="options" id="6" value="6" style="width: 30px;text-align:center; margin-left:30px" onclick="Calculate(this.id)" readonly>
    
<input type="text" class="options" id="9" value="9" style="width: 30px;text-align:center; margin-left:30px" onclick="Calculate(this.id)" readonly><br><br>
```

Comment: you are changing the property of EVERY class element rather than the clicked one. You can just pass _this_ to your function instead of the id.

Comment: Whats the `for loop` doing there?

Comment: @briosheje how am i changing property of each element as id is unique..

Comment: @AbdulJabbar: in the FOR loop you are setting EVERY option's background to blank.

Comment: I want only the clicked box's color to be grey.. so i am first setting every box's color to none and then only changing the one which was clicked..

Comment: @AbdulJabbar : oooh okay! so you want to set back the original style once you click back on another button right? so that's it, just add !important to the :hover in the css, and eventually pass the _this_ to the function, like that: http://jsfiddle.net/fo41gghd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `!important;` after css property, because you are using `background` property in javascript code, that is add style inline so CSS property overwrite by inline css

```js
function Calculate(id)
{
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("options");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i].style.background = 'none';
    }
    document.getElementById(id).style.background = '#d1d1d1';
}
```

```css
.options:hover {
 background:#d1d1d1 !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="options" id="3" value="3" style="width: 30px;text-align:center" onclick="Calculate(this.id)" readonly> 
    
<input type="text" class="options" id="6" value="6" style="width: 30px;text-align:center; margin-left:30px" onclick="Calculate(this.id)" readonly>
    
<input type="text" class="options" id="9" value="9" style="width: 30px;text-align:center; margin-left:30px" onclick="Calculate(this.id)" readonly><br><br>
```

If you don't want to update CSS then you can also use javaScript `removeProperty()` function to remove inline `background` property, see below code

```
function Calculate(id)
{
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("options");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i].style.removeProperty('background');
    }
    document.getElementById(id).style.background = '#d1d1d1';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is your solution. Check if any color then remove it.

```
 if(list[i].style.background != "")
```

Updated example.

```js
function Calculate(id)
{
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("options");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if(list[i].style.background != "")
        list[i].style.background = '';
    }
    document.getElementById(id).style.background = '#d1d1d1';
}
```

```css
.options:hover {
 background:#d1d1d1;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="options" id="3" value="3" style="width: 30px;text-align:center" onclick="Calculate(this.id)" readonly> 
    
<input type="text" class="options" id="6" value="6" style="width: 30px;text-align:center; margin-left:30px" onclick="Calculate(this.id)" readonly>
    
<input type="text" class="options" id="9" value="9" style="width: 30px;text-align:center; margin-left:30px" onclick="Calculate(this.id)" readonly><br><br>
```

Comment: this doesn't work properly - if you click on one element and then click on another, you don't get the hover style for the previous clicked element

Answer (score 1):

instead of setting the background to `'none'`, just set it to `''` and this should remove the background style to let the css take over:

```js
function Calculate(id)
{
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("options");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i].style.background = '';
    }
    document.getElementById(id).style.background = '#d1d1d1';
}
```

```css
.options:hover {
 background:#d1d1d1;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="options" id="3" value="3" style="width: 30px;text-align:center" onclick="Calculate(this.id)" readonly> 
    
<input type="text" class="options" id="6" value="6" style="width: 30px;text-align:center; margin-left:30px" onclick="Calculate(this.id)" readonly>
    
<input type="text" class="options" id="9" value="9" style="width: 30px;text-align:center; margin-left:30px" onclick="Calculate(this.id)" readonly><br><br>
```